# re.search ingores "+" sign when adding a "r" for raw string

Tags: python, regex, rawstring

```
import re

email = input("What's your email? ").strip()

if re.search(r"^.+@.+\.edu$", email):
    print("Valid")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

(FYI: I'm a total beginner when it comes to python)
I'm learning with the help of HarvardX CS50P and have come across a problem.

```
if re.search(r"^.+@.+\.edu$", email):
```

when adding the r, the plus sign is turning white and is not doing what it's supposed to.

the input:

```
My email address is malan@harvard.edu
```

the code regards it as Valid even tho it should return as Invalid.
Is there maybe a problem with how i set up VScode?
I've tried uninstalling regex and installing it again but did not help.

Any Idea what could be the Problem?

Comment: `if re.fullmatch(r"\S+@\S+\.edu", email):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` matches whitespace also.

You can try

```
^\S+@\S+\.edu$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/4gNW4f/1

Comment: Thank you this worked for me! Is it possible that the code they provided is outdated? It worked for Harvard, why not for me ?

Comment: https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/notes/7/